# What its mean to be row and column in matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I understand, what is row and column in the list, array, table, etc but I don't understand it in a plot 
for example, suppose I have something like this
I am showing a code snippet

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
plt.subplots.adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.subplot(1,2,1)  # <---------yeah I wondering about this what does it mean to have row and column how to understand this better
plt.plot(x,y)
```

my question is in comment above. Please help me guys and also I want to know what is the range of the hspace

Comment: Read the documentation carefully, everything is explained there: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html

Answer (score 0):

`subplot(1,2,1)` means, that your figure is split into a table with 1 row, 2 columns and your subplot is at position 1 (row 1 col 1). [Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html):

> If the three integers are nrows, ncols, and index in order, the subplot will take the index position on a grid with nrows rows and ncols columns. index starts at 1 in the upper left corner and increases to the right.

So `subplot(2,2,4)` would add your plot to the figure as a subplot on the bottom right position.

And regarding hspace [Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html):

> The amount of height reserved for space between subplots, expressed as a fraction of the average axis height